# Woocommerce Updating products price with php does not trigger price change notification

Tags: woocommerce

I was playing around with php code where i change price for a certain product. Also i am using a plugin that notify's by email once price fells below some amount. The product price updates with no issues also appears with new price in the product list view, but sadly does not trigger the notification plugin. The strange thing is when i go to product edit and click update i immediately get the notification email.

The php code i am using currently:

```
        $ppt = $value / $divider;
        $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
        print_r($product);
        // Mark product as updated
        update_post_meta($product_id, '_price', $ppt );
        update_post_meta($product_id, '_regular_price', $ppt );
        update_post_meta($product_id, '_sync_updated', true );
        $product->save();
    }
    wp_reset_query();
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You should use WC_Product setter instead update_post_meta.

Try this (not tested) :

```
        $ppt = $value / $divider;
        $product = new WC_Product( $product_id );

        // Mark product as updated
        $product->set_price( $ppt );
        $product->set_regular_price( $ppt );
        $product->save();
    }
    wp_reset_query();
```